# Azure Billing for Classic machines Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-billing-api

Is there a way to get the billing information for classic machines using powershell. I know we can use Get-UsageAggregates for Resoruce Manager. But i want to know for Classic setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no cmdlet same as `Get-UsageAggregates` in Azure ASM mode, because [Get-UsageAggregates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.usageaggregates/v2.1.0/get-usageaggregates) retrieves the reported usage data for the subscription between reportstarttime and reportendtime, **the report contains the billing informations of ASM and ARM.**
Here is my result, the storage 1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961 is a classic storage account:

```
PS > Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime 1/10/2017 -ReportedEndTime 1/13/2017
Usage :
        Usage Start           Usage End             Name                     Meter Category    Meter Name                                                   Quantity
        -----------           ---------             ----                     --------------    ----------                                                   --------
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961 Storage           Standard IO - Page Blob/Disk (GB)                            0.26997 GB
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Identity          S1 Domain Services (Hours)                                   23.9997222222222 Hours
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Networking        IP Address Hours                                             4 Hours
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961 Data Management   Standard IO - Table Write Operation Units (in 10,000s)       0.003 10,000s
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961 Storage           Standard IO - Table (GB)                                     0.00001 GB
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/9/2017 12:00:00 AM  1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Azure App Service Free App Service                                             0.004032 Apps
        1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1/11/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Data Management   Standard IO - Block Blob Write Operation Units (in 10,000s)  0.0049 10,000s
        1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1/11/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Data Management   Standard IO - File Read Operation Units (in 10,000s)         0.0003 10,000s
        1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1/11/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
        1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1/11/2017 12:00:00 AM 1qportalvhdsxxyczk0sy961 Storage           Standard IO - Page Blob/Disk (GB)                            1.295856 GB
        1/10/2017 12:00:00 AM 1/11/2017 12:00:00 AM                          Visual Studio     Free Apps                                                    0.032258064516129 Apps
```

Comment: Do you mean say, after logging using Login-AzureRMaccount, we will be able to get the usage of ASM mode resources?
Correct me if i am wrong. I am new to Azure

Comment: @Venkatakrishnan You are right, this command retrieves the reported usage data for the subscription, we will be able to get the usage of ASM.

Comment: Thanks Jason. It helped